# Is using NSObject's performSelector:... a safe way to implement basic recursion?

Tags: ios, recursion

Is the following (very basic) example a sufficient way to avoid suffering a stack overflow/lock on iOS?

```
- (void)doSomething {
    ...
    [self performSelector:@selector(doSomething) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between `[self performSelector:@selector(doSomething) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}` and `[self doSomething];`

Comment: @MidhunMP There is a HUGE difference. The first isn't recursion, the 2nd is.

Comment: @MidhunMP Traditionally, using performSelector with a value of 0.0 schedules the method for the next cycle of the run loop.

Comment: @Ricky To be clear, your proposed solution technically isn't recursion so it does safely avoid a potential stack overflow. It would help if you better explained your goal.